# Head First Design Patterns - Combined Pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm reading the chapter 12 on the Combined Pattern in Head First Design Patterns.
On page 541,the sample DJView,it cant't run correctly in my computer.when i press the 'start', the program only sounds once rather than circularly .
i'm not sure whether because of the  environment of my system.
but if i add one line code in the method **meta** of the class **BeatModel**,it works.like:

```
  public void meta(MetaMessage message) {
        if (message.getType() == 47) {
            beatEvent();
            sequencer.setMicrosecondPosition(0);  //add this line
            sequencer.start();
            setBPM(getBPM());
        }
    }
```

can anyone tell me why? i'm so confused,is something wrong with the code given by the book or some other reason? help me .
Thanks  in advance!!
**So sorry,the code is long so i could not put all here，you could download from the offical website,here is the link** http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfdp/HeadFirstDesignPatterns_code102507.zip
you can find the sample in this folder '\HeadFirstDesignPatterns_code102507\HF_DP\src\headfirst\combined\djview'.
run the class **DJTestDrive.java** 
 Look forward to  your help.

Comment: You may want to give us something more to work with not everyone will have the book and those that do may not reply. Could we have a bit more code to see your problem properly.

Comment: Could be an error, although I can't find that one on the [official errata list](http://oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=9780596007126)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT #2**: For completeness' sake, the author of Head First Design Patterns Elisabeth Freeman herself has made a note of the fact that the code in her book has only been tested with Java 1.4. She has promised to take our feedback into account.

---

**EDIT:** There seems to be a bug with the `Sequencer.setTempoInBPM` during play. Your approach with setting the microsecond position to `0` is the right approach -- it basically rewinds the sequencer as soon as it ends (i.e. message type = 47).

---

Unfortunately, the sample code seems incorrect. There are several problems:

1. The `sequencer` is not initialized to play in a loop
2. The `meta()` method resets the BPM and renotifies all listeners, but does not reset the sequencer to its original position, which you did to get it to work. However, this method does not need to do anything so long as the sequencer is set to play in a loop.
3. The `off()` method sets the BPM to `0`, which will fast forwards the sequencer to the end of all loops -- which means next time you start the player, it will start from the end and will play nothing.

These change should do the trick:

**#1** In method `BeatModel.buildTrackAndStart`, add `sequencer.setLoopCount` as follows:

```
 public void buildTrackAndStart() {
    // ...
    try {
        sequencer.setSequence(sequence);
        sequencer.setLoopCount(Integer.MAX_VALUE); // play forever
    } catch(Exception e) {
    // ...
}
```

**#2** Remove all statements from method `BeatModel.meta(MetaMessage)`:

```
public void meta(MetaMessage message) {
}
```

**#3** Remove `setBPM(0)` from method `BeatModel.off()`:

```
public void off() {
    // -- remove this -- setBPM(0);
    sequencer.stop();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but your changes seem have a problem:in the **setBPM** method ,sometimes **sequencer.setTempoInBPM(getBPM())** does't work,i find **sequencer.getTempoInBPM()** may return 120 rather than what i have set,you can take a try.

Comment: Alright -- the sequencer has some bugs apparently preventing it from changing the BPM during play -- it defaults sometimes to `120`. Your approach is better -- it basically rewinds the sequence as soon as it ends.

Comment: Hi all, so it's not clear to me if from the comments if the error is in the Sequencer itself or the code using it? (perhaps because of a change in the sequencer in the newer versions of Java??)

If it's an error in the code in the book, please let us know by adding it to the official errata list, thank you!!

Elisabeth (author of Head First Design Patterns)

Comment: @Elisabeth -- the setMicrosecondPosition(0) change must be added regardless. We were not yet able to tell why the BPM cannot be changed during a loop play -- this seems undocumented -- so doing it the way it is in the book seems the safer bet (playing the track again with the new BPM after it stops). This was tested with Java 1.6 b26. Btw, I like the book a lot (bought a copy myself three years ago).

Comment: @Elisabeth -- in the offical errata list ,Someone has already put forward this problem [unconfirmed errata list](http://oreilly.com/catalog/errataunconfirmed.csp?isbn=9780596007126),but it's a unconfirmed errata.what's your tested Java version that can run correctly? i was tested with Java 1.6 b18.

Comment: @nick, @yizhi -- thank you (as you can tell it's been a while since I looked at the errata (d'oh!)).  We have not tried running the code since Java 1.4 but I am planning to do an update here soon... thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

On Java 8 just adding the

sequencer.setMicrosecondPosition(0);

to the BeatModel.meta() makes it work just fine!

Greetings to all,
hebgeenbrug

Answer (score 0):

I meet the similar error when reading. in my computer the processBar doesn`t update.

1.First I add "sequencer.setMicrosecondPosition(0);" in "public void meta(MetaMessage message)" ;

2.Second I delete "sequencer.setLoopCount(Sequencer.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);" in "public void setUpMidi()"; it continuous sound but "meta(MetaMessage message)" will not be notice,so ProcessBar not update.

3.Then it works

may be my experience can help others.